# Writing test case for rendering post list

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I am wanting to write a test for the code below which basically renders all the blog posts such that the latest post is on the top. I am new to React test Library and every time I add my components in the React testing Library I get the following error :

> No overload matches this call.
>     Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly): PostList', gave the following error.
>       Property 'posts' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly'.
>     Overload 2 of 2, '(props: State, context?: any): PostList', gave the following error.
>       Property 'posts' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly'.

**Here is my test file**

```
afterEach(cleanup);
it('renders correctly with all my props', () => {
const post = {
    Name: 'abc',
    title: 'Post title',

  }
  const {getByPlaceholderText, queryByTestId, debug} = render(
     <Notes={notes}/>
  );

        debug();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Generics typings for your `PostList` class component, I noticed that `posts` is a required property for its props. Therefore, when you render your component in your tests, you are required to include the required props (`posts`). Usually, in unit tests, it will be fine to supply your props with mock data.

```
const samplePostsData = {
  1: {
    _id: 1,
    fullName: 'abc',
    title: 'This is the title',
    body: 'Random post created for testing purpose only',
    updatedAt: ''
  }
};

render(<PostList posts={samplePostsData}/>)
```

In addition, key needs to be of type `string`.

```
interface State {
  posts: {
    [key: string]: Post
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi when I add the following snippet to my code the test fails stating "Cannot read property 'renderPosts of undefined'. Here is the code for test file:

test('NewQuestion', () => {
    
    render(<PostList posts={this.renderPosts()}/>)
  
});

Comment: @Rebel I don't think that is the right way of doing things. renderPosts is a method within the component, but you are supposed to supply the `posts` props with expected object, based on the interface

Comment: @Rebel you can just input a sample mock object that fits the typing for the `posts` props

Comment: What error is it giving you? `samplePostsData` should be an object of type `[key: number]: Post`

Comment: No, I don't mean that. I mean, literally a sample object consisting of fake data.

Comment: I have updated my Test.tsx code , with sample object consisting of fake data. It still gives an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206931/discussion-between-wentjun-and-rebel).